# delete rows, that doesn't have references in other tables;

Tags: mysql, sql, reference

I want to delete all rows in database, that doen't have a reference in another table:

this is ok:

```
mysql> DELETE FROM auth_user WHERE username = 'Sample41';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
```

this is not ok:

```
mysql> DELETE FROM auth_user WHERE username = 'Sample98';
ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydatabase`.`school_subjects`, CONSTRAINT `user_id_refs_id_9e8f6fd7` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`))
```

So my goal is to get a query that will delete all users (they will start with 'Sample') that doesn't have reference in other tables ( actually just one table 'school_subjects' )

thank you.,

UPDATE:

```
mysql> describe school_subjects;
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name             | varchar(500) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id          | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_by       | varchar(64)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_time     | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| num_of_followers | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe auth_user;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username     | varchar(30)  | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| first_name   | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name    | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email        | varchar(75)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password     | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_staff     | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_active    | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_superuser | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_login   | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date_joined  | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: please provide both table structure and relation so that we can built the query

Comment: In **any** other table ?

Comment: why hasnt anyone used a JOIN in the delete?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So my goal is to get a query that will delete all users (they will
>   start with 'Sample') that doesn't have reference in other tables (
>   actually just one table 'school_subjects' )

You have a self-referencing table. If you want to delete **all** records you must include `school_subjects` and `auth_user`. Try:

```
DELETE FROM auth_user WHERE username not in (SELECT id FROM auth_user) 
and  username not in (SELECT user_id FROM school_subjects);
```

**UPDATE:** If you don't have a self-referencing constraint and only care about 'school_subjects' try the following query, **note** that it will delete **all** records that are not in conflict with constraints:

```
DELETE FROM auth_user WHERE username not in (SELECT user_id FROM school_subjects);
```

If you need to delete just a few you will need:

```
DELETE FROM auth_user 
WHERE username in ('SomeRecordToBeDeleted', 'one more') AND
username not in (SELECT user_id FROM school_subjects);
```

Comment: ~Database changed
mysql> DELETE FROM auth_user WHERE username not in (SELECT id FROM auth_user )
    -> AND username NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM school_subjects);
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'auth_user' for update in FROM clause
~

Comment: @Vor did you change the error message on your original post? I thought I saw a self-referencing constraint. Since that is not the case I'll update my answer

Answer (score 1):

This will delete rows that don't have a matching 'user_id' in the 'school_subjects' table.

```
DELETE FROM auth_user 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM school_subjects);
```

Comment: you ignore username field.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi: The OP stated that they want a query to remove ALL users that don't have a foreign key constraint pointing to them.  The username was for example only, it appears.

Comment: @Vor, can you verify if this is so?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I already tried the first query, and it deleted everything, I needed, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this--

```
Delete from auth_user where username like 'Sample%' ANd auth_user.id NOT IN 
( select user_id from school_subjects where auth_user.id = school_subjects.user_id)
```